# reading user command to continue does not work

Tags: c, do-while, getchar

I'm Writing a program for Billing System. I'm using do-while loop in my program. And the program is executed according to user input. If the user want to continue the execution, the program will be continue. But I Got a prob in Execution. I was trying my logic in simple do-while loop. The same Problem arises for simple do-while loop also.

```
Problem is: If the input is yes, the program does not get the further input from user.
```

That simple do-while loop is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;
    char ch;
    do
    {
            printf("enter the no less then 4:");
            scanf("%d",&c); 
        switch(c)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("In 1\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("In 2\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("In 3\n");
                break;
        }
        printf("do u want to continue?:");
        ch=getchar();
    }while(ch=='y');
}
```

If i put `while(ch != 'n')` instead of `while(ch=='y')` the program working fine. I couldn't understand the problem behind this. Please Help me to rectify this. And Explain about this problem.Thank u in advance.

Comment: The character 1 does not have the numeric value 1...

Comment: @Dhasneem You always want to run case 3? That is what your current code seems to do.

Comment: Or maybe I completely misubderstood what your program needs to do...

Comment: The switch block is confusing people trying to help you lol

Comment: @ppeterka Yes it does, it is scanned with %d, not %c, but it should be &c instead of c.

Comment: @Cthulhu I have changed.But Now also same problem arises.

Comment: @Cthulhu `fflush(stdin)`is undefined behavior and completely useless.

Comment: @Jens My mistake. Does work with some compilers on input-streams. But yes, a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

first run, 3 is printed, user types "y" and presses return

getchar() reads 'y' and program loops

second time, getchar() reads newline character from the previous key press

newline is not 'y' so program does not loop

Comment: I would not use getchar() in this case, I'd use gets() and then look at the first character of the string it returns

Answer (score 1):

Several problems:

1. getchar returns an int, not a char, so `ch` must be an `int` just like c.
2. scanf needs a pointer to go with the %d, so it should be `scanf("%d", &c);`
3. The `while` should rather test for EOF, as in `while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)`
4. Note that the input will contain the newlines, which you should deal with (e.g. ignore).

This should be quite robust:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int c, ch;

  for (;;) {
    printf ("Enter a number (1, 2 or 3):");
    fflush (stdout);
    if (scanf ("%d", &c) == 1) {
      switch (c) {
      case 1:
        printf ("In 1\n");
        break;
      case 2:
        printf ("In 2\n");
        break;
      case 3:
        printf ("In 3\n");
        break;
      }
      printf ("Do you want to continue? [y/n]:");
      fflush (stdout);
      while ((ch = getchar ())) {
        if (ch == 'y')
          break;
        else if (ch == 'n' || ch == EOF)
          return 0;
      }
    } else {
      printf ("That was not a number. Exiting.\n");
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please help me to come over from this problem? How can ignore the newline?

Answer (score 0):

While(ch=='y') or the character whatever in while() it will sent to case 3 as per your coding....y is pressing ,it wil sent to case 3 otherwise it wont work

Comment: I can't parse this. Care to rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the answer using `getchar`, use `fgets`.

As others explained, the second `getchar` call gives you the newline, which was typed after the first `y`.
With `fgets`, you'll get everything the user typed. Then you can check if it's `y` (just check the first character, or use `strcmp`).